# Solr, Sunspot, SQlite, and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, solr, sunspot

I would like to implement a full text search + faceting for my project that uses SQlite3 as the database. I heard that Solr is really powerful. There are Sunspot & Solr tutorials available but only for MySQL. I can't find any document for how to set it up for SQLite3.

Anyone know how to set it up with SQLite3? Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be exactly the same... AFAIK Solr doesn't work with database directly but rather provides REST API to store, index and search documents.

Comment: Exactly correct. Sunspot merely provides hooks to turn your Ruby models and searches into the correct HTTP calls to Solr.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I saw the error message of connection refuse. It is actually caused by Solr not being started. SQLite is working fine with Solr & Sunspot. This is the tutorial I refer to if you are interested: http://techbot.me/2011/01/full-text-search-in-in-rails-with-sunspot-and-solr/